# Error in snakemake when running conda envs in container

Tags: python, snakemake, conda, singularity

I am facing an issue when running snakemake with a container and conda.
Let me explain better.
I am developing a workflow (locally) in snakemake, where some rules use a conda env (defined in /envs/env.yaml) and other rules use wrappers (so they also are based on conda envs).

An example here:

```
rule clean_spike:
    input:
        sample_ref="{}results/bam/{{id}}.tmp.bam".format(outdir),
        sample_spike="{}results/bam_spike/{{id}}_spike.tmp.bam".format(outdir),
        sample_ref_index="{}results/bam/{{id}}.tmp.bam.bai".format(outdir),
        sample_spike_index="{}results/bam_spike/{{id}}_spike.tmp.bam.bai".format(outdir),
    output:
        sample_ref="{}results/bam/{{id}}.clean.bam".format(outdir),
        sample_spike="{}results/bam_spike/{{id}}_spike.clean.bam".format(outdir),
    conda:
        "../envs/pysam.yaml"
    log:
        "{}results/logs/spike/{{id}}.removeSpikeDups".format(outdir),
    script:
        "../scripts/remove_spikeDups.py"
```

Locally, the pipeline runs smoothly.

Now, I wanted to test the pipeline on another machine (server from the institute), and so I run the command

`snakemake --containerize > Dockerfile`

I got a dockerfile and  I generated an image that was uploaded on dockerhub [here](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/davidebrex/chiprxsnakemake/general).

At this point, I copied the workflow on the other machine, I added to the Snakefile the line:

`containerized: "docker://davidebrex/chiprxsnakemake:latest"`

and tried to run the pipeline with: `snakemake -c 10 --use-conda --use-singularity.`
Ideally, snakemake should run the conda envs within the docker container for each rule

The problem is that i get an error related to the fact that conda is missing..
I checked the docker image and I can run conda and see the installed envs.

**Any suggestions about what is going on?**

Thank you!

This is the error I get:

```
/usr/bin/bash: conda: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 792, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 1246, in execute
    raise e
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 1242, in execute
    success = self.scheduler.schedule()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 636, in schedule
    self.run(runjobs)
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 685, in run
    executor.run_jobs(
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 158, in run_jobs
    self.run(
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 582, in run
    future = self.run_single_job(job)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 635, in run_single_job
    self.cached_or_run, job, run_wrapper, *self.job_args_and_prepare(job)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 623, in job_args_and_prepare
    self.workflow.conda_base_path,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 456, in conda_base_path
    return Conda().prefix_path
           ^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 653, in __init__
    shell.check_output(self._get_cmd("conda info --json"), text=True)
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 61, in check_output
    return sp.check_output(cmd, shell=True, executable=executable, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/davide.bressan-1/mambaforge/envs/new_snakemake/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'conda info --json' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

I tried to change the snakemake command and remove --use-conda but then I get an error related to the fact that the tools are missing.
I checked out other questions on stackoverflow but they were not helpful in my case (like this one: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000711/how-to-use-singularity-and-conda-wrappers-in-snakemake)).

Comment: I have zero experience with `--containerize`, but "I checked the docker image and I can run conda" versus "conda: command not found" when running the workflow really smells like a conda shell setup issue to to me, like people run into when trying to call conda in a script versus interactively.  (No idea where to point you from there, though!)

Comment: Thank you. At the end I changed snakemake version and it worked..quite weird

Comment: Actually now i still get the same error, I also opened an issue on snakemake github, I am clueless